# GSON parsing dynamic JSON field

Tags: java, gson

I can't seem to figure this out.  I've looked at a couple SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson)), and my situation is just a little different.

I'm not sure if I have to register a new TypeToken or what.  But my JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "error": "0",
    "dates": {
        34234 : "2011-01-01" // I want to parse the date into a string.
        87474 : "2011-08-09" // The first values are all unique.
        .                    //this can be any number of entries.
        .
        .
        74857 : "2011-09-22"
    }
}
```

I've created both of my objects like this:

```
public class Response {

    public Integer id;
    public String error;
    public DateList dates;
}
```

Separate file:

```
public class DateList {

    public List<Map<Integer, String>> dateString;
}
```

I'm not sure how to tweek it to get it right.  Documentation doesn't seem to help...  And the other examples I've seen are parsing a custom object, not a string type.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what GSON is, but `List<Map<Integer, String>` is at least missing a `>`. Also, shouldn't it be just a map and not a list of maps?

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy and pasted that code.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried it in this form:

The Json

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "error": "0",
    "dates": {
        "34234" : "2011-01-01"
        "87474" : "2011-08-09"
        "74857" : "2011-09-22"
    }
}
```

And the Response.java

```
public class Response {
    public Integer id;
    public String error;
    public Map<Integer, String> dates;
}
```

At least that seemed to work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew it was something easy!

Comment: Worked for me too. I thought I had to write a custom TypeAdapter or something magical.