# Gson with dynamic name (Android)

Tags: java, android, dynamic, gson

I'm a beginner in java/Android and I try to parse JSON with Gson.

I'm having some difficulty with the files part.
From what I've read I should use MapHash but I'm not sure how to use it in this code

Here my Main class

```
InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
```

The class that do the parsing

```
public class SearchResponse {

    public List<Podcast> podcasts; 

    class Podcast {

        @SerializedName("files")
        private List<File> files;

        @SerializedName("format")
        private String format;

        @SerializedName("title")
        private String title;

    class File {
        private String ValueX;
        private String URLX;
        }
    }
}
```

json structure

```
{
"podcasts": [
    {
    "files": [
        {"NameA": "ValueA"},
        {"NameB": "ValueB"},
        {"...": "..."}
    ],
    "format": "STRING",
    "title": "STRING"
    }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help

here's an edited file of the structure of the JSon I try to parse
http://jsontest.web44.net/noauth.json

Comment: You can parse a JSON even without using Gson. What do you want to get from the JSONObject ?

Comment: I want to get both name and value.

Comment: You alreay have the JSON object with you, which might be a response from somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `File` class you have 2 attributes: `ValueX` and `URLX`. But in your JSON you have 2 fields `NameA` and `NameB`...

Names in JSON response and your class must match, otherwise you won't get any value...

Apart from that, your class structure looks good, and your code for deseralizing looks good as well... I don't think you need any `HashMap`...

---

EDIT: Taking into account your comment, you could use a `HashMap`. You could change your `Podcast` class using:

```
@SerializedName("files")
private List<Map<String,String>> files;
```

And you should get it parsed correctly.

You have to use a `List` because you have a JSON array (surrounded by `[ ]`), and then you can use the `Map` to allow different field names.

Note that you have to delete your `File` class...

Comment: but the name and value are random. I've edited my post to reflect that. I've put a file to show how the json is structured http://jsontest.web44.net/noauth.json

Comment: thanks I've also found my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651953/gson-parsing-dynamic-json-field except mine was like you said really a list