# Dynamically tags parsing Json Data using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSoN data like this:

```
{
   "data": {
      "noofCity": "1",


      "City 1": [
         {
            "id": "12",
            "title": "Delhi"
         }
      ]
   },
   "success": true
}
```

Now based on noofCity next tag City 1 will be generated. If noofCity will be 2 then there are two tag City 1 and City 2. Then how can I parse it using Json? Please tell me how can I generate my POJO class structure.

Comment: If `noofCity` has value 2 will you have two arrays `City 1` and `City 2`? Is that right?

Comment: @konrad Krakowiak yes and also city1 and city 2 will again an array

Comment: you have to put "City 1" and "2". if "City 2" doesn't found, json parser ignores it and "City 2" reference will be null. (and use Gson)

Comment: @wisemann I guess he is not only concern about `"City 1" and "City 2"`. He is concern about handling it dynamically because this list may grow beyond that.

Comment: @kunu you are right .. this list can be grow according to noofCity.

Comment: I guess if you can make all the `City` object to different array then you can use HashMap. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651953/gson-parsing-dynamic-json-field) for reference. However never encounter anything like that so I only can suggest.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Then, this structure a bit wrong. Cities should be list. If you can not change the response, you can write for loop and check 'is city exist'.

Comment: thanks for response. @kunu i have checked the link .. then how can i generate my pojo class.

Comment: @wiseman .. if i use for loop then this is the manual parsing and i can handle it very easly. but i want to parse it with gson.

Comment: @nitin but your data is not suitable for auto parsing. you should change json structure.

Comment: @wisemann thanks. then i will use manual parsing for this.

Comment: @nitintyagi take a look on my answer

Comment: @nitintyagi If you have any question please ask :)

Comment: @nitintyagi Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POJOs should look like below:

Main POJO for Response:

```
public class Response {

    Data data;

    boolean success;
}
```

For Data

```
public class Data {

    int noofCity;
    Map<String, List<City>> cityMap;


    void put(String key, List<City> city){
        if(cityMap == null){
            cityMap = new HashMap<>();
        }
        cityMap.put(key, city);
    }


    public void setNoofCity(int noofCity) {
        this.noofCity = noofCity;
    }

    public int getNoofCity() {
        return noofCity;
    }
}
```

For City

```
public class City {
    int id;
    String title;
}
```

But one of the most important think is a way how to deserialise `Data`. You have to prepare your own deserialiser for this, and define way how to fill `HashMap` as is shown in the code below:

```
public class DataDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Data> {

    @Override
    public Data deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Data result  = new Data();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject=  json.getAsJsonObject();
        result.setNoofCity(jsonObject.get("noofCity").getAsInt());

        for(int i =1; i<=result.getNoofCity() ; i++ ){
           List<City> cities=  gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("City "+ i), List.class);
            result.put("City "+ i, cities);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And now you can deserialise you json

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataDeserializer())
            .create();
 Response test = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

Comment: Krakowiask .. thanks for the answer...your answer works fine in my case. thanks again....