# Parsing JSON using Google GSON: reading values directly from child objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having trouble parsing the following JSON with Google's Gson:

```
{"Name":
    {"object1":   
       {"field1":"17",
        "field2":"360",
        "field3":"19",
        "field4":"sun",
        "field5":"rain"
       }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following to get the value of field1 but it doesn't work

```
@SerializedName("Name/object1/field1")
public int fieldOne;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1. Kind of surprising that Gson doesn't seem to have a notation like `@SerializedName("Name/object1")` or `@SerializedName("Name.object1")` for getting values from child objects directly.

Comment: (Btw, removed Android tag as this is not Android specific at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objects have to conserve the hierarchy of your json instructions. For your example, it would be something like this:

```
public class Object {

    @SerializedName("field1")
    public String fieldOne;

    @SerializedName("field2")
    public String fieldTwo;

    @SerializedName("field3")
    public String fieldThree;

    @SerializedName("field4")
    public String fieldFour;
}

public class Name {

    @SerializedName("object1")
    public Object obj;
}

public class GsonObj {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    public Name name;
}
```

Using the following call:

```
String json = "{\"Name\":{" +
            "\"object1\":{" +
            "\"field1\":\"17\",\"field2\":\"360\",\"field3\":\"19\",\"field4\":\"sun\",\"field5\":\"rain\"}}}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
GsonObj jsonResult = gson.fromJson(json, GsonObj.class);
Log.d("test", "field one: "+jsonResult.name.obj.fieldOne);
Log.d("test", "field two: "+jsonResult.name.obj.fieldTwo);
Log.d("test", "field three: "+jsonResult.name.obj.fieldThree);
Log.d("test", "field four: "+jsonResult.name.obj.fieldFour);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid JSON. JSON may either start with { or [ so you need to wrap your string with another pair of {}.

A good practice is to always check your data first. I often use this here:
http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: sorry i missed those brackets, I do have them

Comment: You still miss 1 bracket. Just at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have "Name/object1/field" you have to specify key name directly without hierarchy.
refer [How to parse dynamic JSON fields with GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson)