# How to split belowed json array at android?

Tags: java, android

```
[596456 fae4b088b3c5171c19: {
    "amount": "10",
    "career": "AIRTEL",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "8998899898",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PrePaid"
}, 59645776e4 b038c5b67330bc: {
    "amount": "45",
    "career": "AIRTEL POSTPAID",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "54345354",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PostPaid"
}, 59645780e4 b038c5b67330bd: {
    "amount": "45",
    "career": "DISH TV",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "45545545454",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "DTH"
}, 5964578 ce4b038c5b67330c1: {
    "amount": "455",
    "career": "MTS MBLAZE",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "54545454",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "DataCard"
}, 596464 cbe4b038c5b67334c3: {
    "amount": "43",
    "career": "TATA INDICOM",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "4343344343",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PrePaid"
}, 596466 ade4b078c759fe36bc: {
    "amount": "8989",
    "career": "AIRTEL",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "87787887",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PrePaid"
}, 596466 dce4b078c759fe36cb: {
    "amount": "876",
    "career": "AIRTEL",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "80",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PrePaid"
}, 596466e8 e4b078c759fe36cd: {
    "amount": "80",
    "career": "AIRTEL",
    "userid": "596360d8e4b0690c95470b43",
    "number": "8098898998",
    "date": "11-07-2017",
    "type": "PrePaid"
}]
```

I want to form an listview using amount,career,date..how to split this json?kindly give your reviews

Comment: Your json syntax as wrong check this link http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: Are u check it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: Your json data is dynamic. you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111401/using-the-gson-library-to-parse-unknown-data-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Well your JSON isn't proper one.

There's a really good post about understanding JSON parsing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/7535961)