# Deserialize JSON Array with random name - GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

Am trying to deserialize a complex JSON structure using GSON. The API provider complicates things by providing an array in the results with a random name.

This is the (simplified/generified) JSON:

```
{
    "field_1": "value",
    "field_2": "value",
    "field_3": {
        "RANDOM_NAME": [
            {
                "array_field_1": "value",
                "array_field_2": "value",
                "array_field_3": "value"
            },
            {
                "array_field_1": "value",
                "array_field_2": "value",
                "array_field_3": "value"
            }
        ]
    },
    "field_4": "value"
}
```

and this is the corresponding (highly simplified) POJO:

```
public class responseObject {
    String field_1;
    String field_2;
    Field3 field_3;
    String field_4;

    class Field3{
        ArrayObject[] arrayObjects;
    }
    class ArrayObject{
        String array_field_1;
        String array_field_2;
        String array_field_3;
    }
}
```

However, when i run `responseObject response = new Gson().fromJson(getJSON(),responseObject.class);` i get the following call stack:

[image: autos]

indicating that `field_3` was not properly deserialized and does not contain an array of `ArrayObject`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23472175) post the answers reference how to convert the data  to a map, but in my case the data structure of each item in the array is actually much larger than this simplified example, and it defeats the purpose of using GSON if i have to manually pick the data i need out of a complex list of nested maps. also having trouble getting these answers to work in my scenario where the random object is an array an not a plain json object.

how do i get the randomly named array in the JSON to properly deserialize into the variable `responseObject.Field3.arrayObjects`??

Comment: This is a complex structure. How about a 2 step deserialization? first step will be to use map with <String, String>. after that deserialize the value String again.

Comment: can you demonstrate how to do that in one or two easy steps with gson?

Comment: Something like this:
1st step:
public class responseObject {
    String field_1;
    String field_2;
    Field3 field_3;
    String field_4;

    class Field3{
        Map<String, String> field_3;
    }
    class ArrayObject{
        String array_field_1;
        String array_field_2;
        String array_field_3;
    }
}

2nd step:
for(String key: field_3.keySet()) {
 //apply deserialization for field_3.get(key)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the complexity of using a TypeAdapeter by making the type of field_3  `Map<String, List<ArrayObject>>`

```
public class responseObject {
    String field_1;
    String field_2;
    Map<String, List<ArrayObject>> field_3;
    String field_4;

    class ArrayObject{
        String array_field_1;
        String array_field_2;
        String array_field_3;
    }
}
```

And then to get the first item out of the Map without knowing its key you can use:

```
public List<ResponseObject.ArrayObject> getFirstValue(Map<String, List<ResponseObject.ArrayObject>> field_3) {
    return field_3.values().iterator().next();
}
```

Comment: working! thank you. accepted this answer because it avoids having to write a custom `TypeAdapter` which is more in the spirit of the simplicity of `GSON`s easy deserializing...

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by writing a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for `Field3` which ignores the name of the property and only reads the value. The `TypeAdapter` has to be created by a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) to allow getting the delegate adapter for `ArrayObject[]`:

```java
class Field3TypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public Field3TypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Only support Field3 class
        if (type.getRawType() != Field3.class) {
            return null;
        }

        TypeAdapter<ArrayObject[]> fieldValueAdapter = gson.getAdapter(ArrayObject[].class);

        // Cast is safe, check at beginning made sure type is Field3
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<Field3>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Field3 value) throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Serialization is not supported");
            }

            @Override
            public Field3 read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    in.nextNull();
                    return null;
                }

                in.beginObject();
                // Skip the random property name
                in.skipValue();
                ArrayObject[] fieldValue = fieldValueAdapter.read(in);
                in.endObject();

                Field3 object = new Field3();
                object.arrayObjects = fieldValue;
                return object;
            }
        };
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

You can then either [register the factory with a `GsonBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapterFactory(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory)), or you can annotate your `Field3` class with [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html). When using `@JsonAdapter` the factory class should have a no-args constructor.