# How to parse Dynamic lists with Gson annotations?

Tags: gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and Gson to query an API, however I have never come across a JSON response like it.

The Response:

```
{
    Response: {
        "Black":[
            {"id":"123","code":"RX766"},
            {"id":"324","code":"RT344"}],
        "Green":[
            {"id":"3532","code":"RT983"},
            {"id":"242","code":"RL982"}],
        "Blue":[
            {"id":"453","code":"RY676"},
            {"id":"134","code":"R67HJH"}]
    }
}
```

The problem is the list elements id eg "black" is dynamic, so I a have no idea what they will be.

So far I have created a class for the inner type;

```
class Type {
    @SerializedName("id") private String id;
    @SerializedName("code") private String code;
}
```

Is it possible to have the following?

```
class Response {

    @SerializedName("response")
    List<Type> types;
}
```

And then move the list ID into the type, so the Type class would become;

```
class Type {
    @SerializedName("id") private String id;
    @SerializedName("code") private String code;
    @SerializedName("$") private String type; //not sure how this would be populated
}
```

If not, how else could this be parsed with just Gson attributes?

Ok so I have just seen this question;
[How to parse dynamic JSON fields with GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson?rq=1)

which looks great, is it possible to wrap a generic map with the response object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the keys are dynamic you want a map.

```
class Response {
    @SerializedName("response")
    Map<String, List<Type>> types;
}
```

After deserialization you can coerce the types into something more semantic in your domain.

If this is not suitable you will need to register a `TypeAdapter` or a `JsonDeserializer` and do custom deserialization of the map-like data into a simple `List`.

Comment: @Jake Could u please help for following parsing, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33758601/2624806)