# Parsing dynamic JSON to POJO with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Hi I have json which has some dynamic field names:

```
{
"status": {
    "rcode": 200,
    "message": "OK"
},
"data": {
    "0": {
        "SubFranchiseID": "0",
        "OutletID": "607",
        "OutletName": "Spill "
    },
    "1": {
        "SubFranchiseID": "0",
        "OutletID": "32",
        "OutletName": "PizzaRoma"
    }
},
"hash": "b262c62ea3c8c693ad35210289a487d6963434d7"
```

}

"0" and "1" are dynamic String values.

From here [How to parse Dynamic lists with Gson annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898510/how-to-parse-dynamic-lists-with-gson-annotations)

I created my Data class as :

```
public class Data {

   public Map<String, Restaurant> restaurants = new HashMap<>();;

   public Map<String, Restaurant> getRestaurants() {
      return restaurants;
   }
}
```

But I am getting zero value when i use getRestaurants().size() in Retrofit.

How should change my Data class ?

Edit :

My main class :

```
public class MyClass{

private Status status;
private Data data;
private String hash;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}
// other getter and setters
}
```

Retrofit and RxJava :

```
RetrofitService service1 = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.API_ENDPOINT);
    service1.data()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyClass>() {

                @Override
                public final void onNext(MyClass response) {

                    if(response.getData().getRestaurants().size() == 0)
                        Log.d("1", "size is ZERO ");

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to not use the Data class , instead I changed my MyClass as:

```
public class MyClass{

private Status status;

@SerializedName("data")
private Map<String, Restaurant> data;

private String hash;

public Map<String, Restaurant> getData() {
    return data;
}
// other getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below two classes should work for you.

```
class Data {
    Map<String, List<Outlet>> types;
}

class Outlet {
String SubFranchiseID;
String OutletID;
String OutletName;
}
```

Comment: Still getting getRestaurants().size() as zero

Comment: please post your main class as well