# dynamic notation serializedname

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I have several services that return three fields (json).
FailureMessage (string, in case something wrong happens)
Success (boolean)
[Custom] (object of return)
Examples below:

1)

```
{
    "FailureMessage": "",
    "Success": true,
    "Cities": []
}
```

2)

```
{
    "FailureMessage": "",
    "Success": true,
    "Regions": []
}
```

Is there a way to map then in a generic way?

Now, I have the first 2 properties mapped to a GenericResponse, and other classes extending GenericResponse and creating the third attribute in each one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson) something that might apply to your problem?

Comment: As @JonasKöritz said, you will use reflection. However, to decide which to parse, you will need to parse rawly like JsonNode or something to decide which class to reflect

Comment: I'd really like to avoid maps, if it can't be done, that I'd rather do it by extending common fields.

Comment: @JonasKöritz - set your comment as answer, so I can close this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson) should be usable as a solution to your problem.

You will have to provide gson with a method of parsing your specific structure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)