# Parse json data with retrofit

Tags: json, retrofit, retrofit2, android, gson

I got dynamic number of key in json object it will be change according to data i am using retrofit

JSON

```
{
"response_message": "Settings has been displayed successfully",
"deliveryCharges": [
  {
    "iSettingId": 2,
    "vSettingDescription": "deliveryCharges",
    "vSettingName1": 1,
    "vSettingName2": 1.5,
    "vSettingName3": 1.75,
    .
    .
    .
    "vSettingNamen": 1.75
  },
  {
    "iSettingId": 3,
    "vSettingDescription": "deliveryCharges",
    "vSettingName1": 1,
    "vSettingName2": 1.5,
    "vSettingName3": 1.75,
    .
    .
    .
    "vSettingNamen": 1.75
  },
  {
    "iSettingId": 4,
    "vSettingDescription": "deliveryCharges",
    "vSettingName1": 1,
    "vSettingName2": 1.5,
    "vSettingName3": 1.75,
    .
    .
    .
    "vSettingNamen": 1.75
  }
]
}
```

here i can get n number of vSettingName. It is totally dynamic so how can i make POJO for this

Comment: Please show your code, what you have tried till now

Comment: Take a look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796948/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-fields-with-gson

Comment: @DeepKakkar i dont know how to make this type of dynamic POJO

Comment: @SimY4 thank you i am able to parse data now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType(); //define generic type
List<Map<String, String>> result = gson.fromJson(deliveryCharges,mapType);
```